# How to log out without confirmation 'Do you really want to log out?"?

Tags: logout

Right now when I log out via:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout">Log out</a>
```

it redirects me to the page where I need to confirm the log out.

How to eliminate the confirmation and redirect to the homepage after logout?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This happens because you are missing the neccessary nonce in the URL, which is being checked in `wp-login.php`

```
case 'logout' :
    check_admin_referer('log-out');
    ...
```

Use `wp_logout_url` in order to retreive the URL including the nonce. If you want to redirect to a custom URL, simply pass it as an argument.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('/redirect/url/goes/here') ?>">Log out</a>
```

You could also use `wp_loginout` which generates the link for you including translation:

```
echo wp_loginout('/redirect/url/goes/here')
```

Comment: echo wp_loginout('/redirect/url/goes/here') is working fine..

Comment: I'm using `wp_logout_url( get_permalink())` and the confirmation page is not bypassed. The nonce is generated as part of the URL but I am still sent to the confirmation page

Comment: Same issue here :(

Answer (score 31):

If you can't use `wp_logout_url()` function, You can turn off this validation using this code:

```
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'logout_without_confirm', 10, 2);
function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)
{
    /**
     * Allow logout without confirmation
     */
    if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {
        $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : 'url-you-want-to-redirect';
        $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));
        header("Location: $location");
        die;
    }
}
```

Replace `'url-you-want-to-redirect'` with the URL you want to redirect after logout.

Add it in your `functions.php`

Comment: This works for logging out without validation, but it doesn't redirect to the url I want.

Comment: @PhuNguyen You just need to add the redirect URL to the redirect request in that code where there is '  ' quotes, after the colon.

Comment: are there any security implications for removing this validation?

Comment: @user1264304 I believe malicious JS somehow loaded into the browser could do a redirect to the login page, but all it's going to do is logout the user. Truly malicious code would probably seek to replace the URL before a valid nonce. The user could navigate to another site which then has a link the current site's logout page - assuming the other site is aware that the user has a relationship. Again, no consequence other than logging out the user. I've never seen this. So to answer your question, I do Not think there is a security implication for removing the validation.

Comment: Err, Too Many Redirects...

Comment: Excellent solution for me especially because it needs no extra php on my logout page. I simply use this link:wp-login.php?action=logout
And as redirect, I use home_url() so it works on any site.

Comment: We can sure use the wp_logout_url.
And this is what you need:

$location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));

Just direct to that $location and you will logout without confirmation.

Comment: This is a great solution for me, but also find it is not redirecting.  I just get dumped back on home page...

Comment: This is an ideal solution for adding a logout button to a wp menu.

Answer (score 13):

If you create a custom link in your menu, set the label to `“Logout”`, and set the URL to `http://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout`. Then add this function to your `functions.php` file:

```
function change_menu($items){
  foreach($items as $item){
    if( $item->title == "Logout"){
         $item->url = $item->url . "&_wpnonce=" . wp_create_nonce( 'log-out' );
    }
  }
  return $items;

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```

If you want to redirect to the login page after logout then you should append login URL as:

```
$item->url = $item->url . "&_wpnonce=" . wp_create_nonce( 'log-out' ).'&redirect_to='.wp_login_url();
```

[Reference link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-logout-confirmation/)

** tried that did not work. Really want to log out page then 4 something went wrong when clicking the button.

Comment: This completely worked for me, including the redirect. You have to be careful to use correct PHP formatting to add a link. Here's my code for that line: `$item->url = $item->url . "&_wpnonce=" . wp_create_nonce( 'log-out' ).'&redirect_to='.'https://google.com';`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me by adding `/?customer-logout=true` at the end.

`http://www.website.com/?customer-logout=true`

Comment: This worked well for me, too... But maybe it can be used only if WooCommecre is installed... I don't know...

Answer (score 4):

If you're using roots/sage wordpress starter theme, or any other theme using Laravel's Blade templating engine, make sure not to escape the url:

```php
// don't do
<a href="{{ wp_logout_url(get_permalink()) }}">log out</a>

// but instead
<a href="{!! wp_logout_url(get_permalink()) !!}">log out</a>
```

First example escapes all html characters, while the latter does not.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass logout confirmation prompt define `_wpnonce` for `log-out` action in the URL like this:

```
$log_out_url = add_query_arg('_wpnonce', wp_create_nonce('log-out'), wp_logout_url());

wp_safe_redirect($log_out_url);
exit;
```