# Logout and redirect using the WP Menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, redirect, navigation

I have a navigation hyperlink in my secondary menu, that will allow the user to logout:

[image]

However, the user is prompted with the following screen for confirmation, when clicking on the hyperlink in the secondary navigation menu:

[image]

I am currently using the following URL in the navigation menu to redirect the user back to the *Accounts* page, as a temporary measure:

```
http://mywebsitenamehere.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http://mywebsitenamehere.com/my-account/
```

Is there a way that I can use the WordPress menu above, and place in an appropriate URL to log the user out without the confirmation screen, and then send them back to the page that they were previously on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hook into the wp_nav_menu_items filter to get the correct link with the nonce, [as described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out#answer-67342) . An example of how to do that can be seen here https://gist.github.com/theukedge/6565746#file-gistfile1-php