# Wordpress Logout Problem

Tags: login

I'm wondering why is it that when I log out, I see something like this in the address bar and it doesn't really log me out from the site?

Please help!

http://sample.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=c123467bd1

Comment: Have you tried clearing out your browser cache or tried a different browser?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in this post: [How to log out without confirmation 'Do you really want to log out?"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out)

side note: running an old version of WP like that (3.6) is super risky from a security standpoint. Do your future self a favor and update it!