# Change button link to add nonce

Tags: php, buttons, nonce, logout

I am making a Logout button, but in order for it to work properly the link needs to have the correct nonce ("site.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&wp_nonce=X".
I have found in another question ([How to log out without confirmation 'Do you really want to log out?"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out)) a way to add the nonce, but it is only for menu links:

```
  foreach($items as $item){
    if( $item->title == "Logout"){
         $item->url = $item->url . "&_wpnonce=" . wp_create_nonce( 'log-out' );
    }
  }
  return $items;

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```

How can I do the same for a button?

Comment: I have found the best solution and explanation: https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-logout-without-confirmation-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_logout_url()

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it just takes me litereally to link "website.com/<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" ...

Comment: Where are you putting the code?

Comment: I am putting it in a HTML module through elementor

Comment: This is PHP, will not work this way

Comment: how can i make it work, please?