# Log out without confirmation request (nonce)

Tags: php, login, nonce, logout

I have a Wordpress site with WooCommerce. I would like to add a Logout option to the Menu that logs out the user *without asking for confirmation*.

So I included a menu custom link with as URL: `/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=3d7c353c19&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com`. However, the nonce changes every time, so it will still ask for confirmation to log out...

[This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67342) shares something about how to get rid of the confirmation request with php. But I'm not familiar with php. How should I use this in the URL field of the custom link? That is, how can I populate the custom url with the dynamic nonce?

Comment: Without PHP you probably can't do this.

Comment: If you use wp_logout_url() and pass it the urn (without the domain) that you want the user  to be redirected to after logout, you will not see any confirmation request.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, the problem is I have no idea how to use wp_logout_url() or pass it something...

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I think OP is currently only using wp-admin tools, where they manually added a menu item with the posted URL. @Nick `wp_logout_url()` is a PHP method, you need to familiarize yourself with PHP, find a plugin that solves this, or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: All right, thanks, I was afraid of that. It just felt strange that it's not a regular option in Wordpress itself.

Comment: @kero wp_logout_url is a wordpress function not a PHP method, wp_logout_url returns a logout url, thats it. you can create a html a tag with href and output wp_logout_url there

Comment: @kero, is it also possible to add the php method using the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/ ? (because I'd rather not change anything directly inside the theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it using the plugin [Code Snippets](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) and the following code snippet based on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67342:

```
function change_menu($items){
    foreach($items as $item){
        if( $item->title == "Log Out"){
            $item->url = wp_logout_url('/');
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `wp_logout_url()` is your best choice.

You will need to create a `<a>` tag and in the href attribute output wp_logout_url()

```
<a href="<?= wp_logout_url('/'); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

I passed `/` as an argument because after the user will click the link he will be redirected back to the homepage, you can change it to what ever you want

> EDIT

Using code snippets you could create a shortcode and then use it, almost, where ever you want.

```
add_shortcode('bt_custom_logout_link', 'bt_custom_logout_link');
function bt_custom_logout_link ($atts) {
    $link = '<a href="' . wp_logout_url('/') . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
    return $link;
}
```

This function will register a new shortcode named `bt_custom_logout_link`, to use it you need to type it like this `[bt_custom_logout_link]`

Comment: I don't think Wordpress accepts that as a custom link. When I enter that and click on Save, Wordpress converts the url to `http://a%20href=?=%20wp_logout_url('/');%20?%20title=LogoutLogout/a`. See: https://ibb.co/yy66S1F

Comment: Seems like you are trying to add this code inside a wysiwyg as link option, this is not possible. wysiwyg with link option will escape any special characters. you will need to go inside your theme and add it there. or find the right action to hook into it and output the code

Comment: I'm using the default Appearance > Menus option that comes with Wordpress. I've now also installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/. Is it perhaps also possible with a code snippet?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the code you need to add to code snippets in order to create a shortcode that will output a logout link

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. If I look in the source code what this produces, is `<a href="http://[bt_custom_logout_link]" class="menu-link">Log Out</a>` So it doesn't replace the url. The snippet is activated and set to run everywhere, so that can't be the problem. I litereally copy-pasted your code.

Comment: putting the shorcode inside the link input will not work, try adding it in a wysiwyg and see what it outputs, if its what you want then try to find the right wysiwyg that works best for you

Comment: There's no wysiwyg editor available under Wordpress's Appearance > Menus. I don't think that is something available here in Wordpress.